# how to make the user logout automatically if the token is refreshed

Tags: flutter, dart, token

I have a problem here, what if the user is logged in and the token expires, it returns to the login page, because in my case, when the token expires or is refreshed, the user doesn't return to the login page, instead it returns an error in the form of text.

> call API

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late User _user;
  User get user => _user;

  set user(User newUser) {
    _user = newUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<User?> login(String nim, String password) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    try {
      var body = {
        'username': nim,
        'password': password,
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
          '$url/login_mhs',
        ),
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['access_token'];
        await UtilSharedPreferences.setToken(token);
        print(token);
        return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

> in splashscreen

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Future<void> toLogin() async {
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String? token = prefs.getString(Constant.token);
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          token != null ? AppRoute.mainRoute : AppRoute.loginRoute,
          arguments: token,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    toLogin();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get an expire time from the backend?

Comment: yes, the backend has been validated, when I try it in the browser when the token expires, the user returns to the login page

Answer (score -1):

**The first solution using an HTTP interceptor:**

You can use an HTTP interceptor to catch the response and check if the error is 401 Unauthorized. If so, you can log the user out of the app.

```dart
import 'package:http_interceptor/http_interceptor.dart';

class AuthInterceptor implements InterceptorContract {
  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({required RequestData data}) async {
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({required ResponseData data}) async {
    if (data.statusCode == 401) {
      logOut();
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

**The second solution using a timer:**

If you get an expiration time for the token from the backend, you can set a timer to this time and log the user out when the timer ends.

```dart
  Timer? _timer;
  
  void setTokenExpiration(DateTime expirationTime) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final expiresIn = expirationTime.difference(now);
    _timer = Timer(expiresIn, logOut);
  }
```

Comment: can you give an example of how i made it?

Comment: @Meikisihka I added examples

Comment: Using timers is a good option? does it make a storage lake? to keep a timer working for weeks!

Comment: @mNouh It depends on the specific application. For example, in banking applications, tokens live for only a couple of minutes, and each time the user opens the application, they must authenticate and get a new token. In this case, you can use a timer and log the user out when the token expires. For applications where the user can stay logged in for months, this is not suitable.